# _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING in basic_string.h

Tags: c++, string

In the code for basic_string.h the define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING is queried what is it exactly meant to do ?
Do you have any example of use ?

Comment: It is an implementation detail define and generally not meant for the end user; it is supposed to make the string implementation fully standards compliant (i.e. not refcounted)

Comment: So may I define it and eliminate refcounting and the field _M_refcount of the structure ?

Comment: An the field _M_refcount of the structure ?

Comment: As long as you don't share std::strings with other libraries.

Comment: I don't see in the code the field _M_refcount depending it's existence on the definition of _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING, should it be like that ?

Answer (score 1):

`_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING=1` disables using shared empty string representation.